# Complexity of insert in Hash Table

Tags: hash, time-complexity, hashtable

Consider an initially empty hash table of size M and hash function h(x) = x mod M. In the worst case, what is the time complexity (in Big-Oh notation) to insert n keys into the table if separate chaining is used to resolve collisions (without rehashing)? Suppose that each entry (bucket) of the table stores an unordered linked list. When adding a new element to an unordered linked list, such an element is inserted at the beginning of the list.

Comment: Does the insert need to drop elements equal/identical to ones already inserted or are duplicates in the table allowed?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the *absence* of collisions, inserting a key into a hash table/map is `O(1)`, since looking up the bucket is a constant time operation.  I would not expect this to vary in the case of collisions, assuming that collisions are resolved using a linked list *and* that the new element is inserted to the head of the list.  The reason for this is that adding an new element to the head of a linked list it also basically `O(1)`.  So, inserting under these assumptions should also be `O(1)`, and therefore inserting `n` keys should be `O(n)`.

Comment: You cannot blindly add an element to the head of the linked list as you need to first look if it's not present. Well you *could* blindly add it and not care if there are duplicates but then it takes more space than the number of items and you have to scan the full list when deleting a key of the map since you will need to delete all duplicates, so it's not the best approach